# Open `.ipynb` file with Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to use Spark with Zeppelin. I downloaded a tutorial which is contained by an `.ipynb` notebook.

I can see `.ipynb` is usually opened with the IPython notebook.

Is there a way of using that with Zeppelin instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, they are not compatible out-of-the box. `ipynb` is a specific format for IPython notebooks.

Zeppelin doesn't support importing such format for now.